# Can someone with permission remove link on tag info page please

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-wiki

Not really a question,
can someone with 5k points remove bigqueri.es from https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-bigquery/info as it's not a site about Google Bigquery, it's some affiliate shopping site.

Comment: I'm going to assume that it was once a site about bigquery as it's been there for 4 years! Anyway, it's been removed now, nice spot!

Comment: Daft question, should I vote to close my own question or delete? @rene

Comment: No, you can just leave it, no need to delete or close it. The status tag is enough.